# SQL Query: Select Future Events And Order By Name Alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have an issue to sort a SQL results and really would appreciate your help.
So here is the situation:

- Table1 holds city names and city IDs.
- Table2 holds some events and the ID of the city where the event is going to happen.

The query should retrieve all the future events, sorted alphabetically by city.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your schema.

Comment: @Kerrek: Don't you mean `ORDER BY City`?

Comment: @cdhowie: Yes, sorry! Fixed :-)

Comment: Hey @ Boris. The title of this question should be more specific and in future please show your attempt at solving it.

Comment: @feeela, you are wrong, i did :) nvm maybe i missed the answer while searching. Thanks anyway to all of you.

Comment: Ok, im going to answer this one just to respect you, it's not the order by that i was looking for, now when i saw the answer of Yahia, my problem (what i didnt knew) was now to "connect" the two tables in one query. Good night.

Comment: @feeela: Because without the schema, we don't know the column or table names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT T1.CityName, T2.EventStart, T2.EventDescription FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2 WHERE 
T1.CityID = T2.CityID AND T2.EventStart > NOW()
ORDER BY T1.CityName ASC, T2.EventStart ASC
```

EDIT - As per comment

```
SELECT 
T1.CityName, 
T2.EventStart, 
T2.EventDescription 
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.CityID = T2.CityID 
WHERE T2.EventStart > NOW()
ORDER BY T1.CityName ASC, T2.EventStart ASC
```

Comment: glad I could help - then please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the box on the left side

Comment: Has anybody heard of the "new" `JOIN` keyword?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2 
  WHERE t1.id=t2.id 
   AND t2.event_date > NOW()  
  ORDER BY t1.city_name ASC
```

Comment: @Hydra: Try using the `JOIN` syntax instead of the (implicit) join with `WHERE`